# Why is Bundler repeatedly choosing gems that require a newer version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've just started working on a very old legacy app for a client, which is running on Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2, and using JRuby on the production server.  (Obstacles in upgrading the server has been a contributor to remaining on 1.9.3.)

Adding a gem to the Gemfile, even though the gem is compatible with 1.9.3, and even though I've added

```
ruby '1.9.3', :patchlevel => '551'
```

to the top of the Gemfile, Bundler continually chooses versions of other gems that require Ruby 2.0, and so updating fails.  How can I get around this, without having to manually specify *every* single gem version that it fails on.

For example:

```
...
Using quiet_assets 1.1.0
Using rails 3.2.22
Using ref 2.0.0
Using rspec-rails 2.14.2
Fetching rspec_junit_formatter 0.3.0 (was 0.2.3)
Installing rspec_junit_formatter 0.3.0 (was 0.2.3)
Gem::InstallError: rspec_junit_formatter requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing rspec_junit_formatter (0.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rspec_junit_formatter -v '0.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I had to specify `gem 'rspec_junit_formatter', '0.2.3'`, ***as well as all of the previous failures***, in order to get this working.  But that seems to defeat the purpose of Bundler.  Why is Bundler ignoring Ruby versions when it builds its dependency graph, even though I've explicitly told it what version of Ruby to use?

Comment: I was a little surprised to find this comment from 2014: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2965#issuecomment-39469017

Comment: wow, that _is_ surprising, especially the claim that it's not a bug for bundler to build a dependency graph that fails, because it has never paid attention to Ruby versions in the past. I guess this is a good example of ***how different people can have radically different ideas of what a bug is***.  In my mind, the fact that _it has always failed to handle a certain use case in performing its one job_ does not change the fact that it's failing to do its one job.  But then... I guess he and I have a different definition of its job...

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is not ignoring the ruby version. When it installs gems it does not look at each gem and do a smart pick of which one to choose to get rid of any dependency issues (including the ruby version dependency).

In your gemfile, by not specifying the gem version, bundler will try to install the highest version it can. This is why it is good practice to specify exact versions for all your gems- so that if an update comes out for a gem in the repo you are getting the gem from- your project does not break.

Specifying the ruby version in the gem file is just like specifying the gem version for particular gem- it installs that version but does not affect the installation of any other gems.

Comment: "This is why it is good practice to specify exact versions for all your gems"—if I have to figure out the exact versions of every Gem, then I have to do Bundler's job before I let Bundler do it's job. Why would I do that?

Comment: "so that if an update comes out for a gem in the repo you are getting the gem from- your project does not break."—that's what Gemfile.lock is for.  It tracks exact versions.  If a new version breaks my code, I then have new information that did not exist before it came out, and I can then specify in Gemfile not to use that version.

Comment: "Bundler is not ignoring the ruby version." I'm not sure what you mean by this.  It seems pretty clear to me from the GitHub issue linked to in the question's first comment that ***Bundler is not taking into account Ruby versions in building the dependency graph***.   So, at least at that point in its operation, it is doing nothing with the information I gave it, which I consider to be ignoring that information.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Overall bundler is not ignoring the ruby version- but it does not take into account versions when dealing with dependency issues. This is what I mentioned in my answer. The dependency issues are clearly outputted to the console so they should be easy to resolve by specifying version numbers. 


This is just the behavior of bundler and gemfiles.